# Load localized .strings files with accent marks in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, character-encoding

I'm working on localizing my iPhone app, and my translators are doing an excellent job. The problem is that the accent marks and "non-standard" characters keep on getting ruined by Xcode. I'm not quite sure what the issue is, but it's just not working correctly. I've tried changing the encoding, and some are better than others, but in the end, I'm getting some pretty interesting results.

I've tried the default, UTF-8, which my translator said he had sent me. (He also sent me ANSI BOM, but, I'm not sure what that would be equal to in Xcodese.)

[image: Default Xcode encoding]

I tried to change the encoding...

[image: changing the character encoding]

but I got this instead:

[image: wrong character encoding]

How would you suggest fixing this? I want my French, Spanish, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the translated text, then open this file with UTF16 - remove everything, and then paste the translated text. That should do the trick.

Comment: What program would be able to open it on Mac? I haven't had much luck with anything, actually.

Comment: I'm able to open it in Safari, with a .html extension.

Comment: This works, +1, but I'd like to know what went wrong when I opened the file initially. I saved with the default encoding though.

Comment: The problem is that the default encoding is not UTF-16. When you save with it and open with UTF-16 - this does not mean conversion. Before writing a file better set the encoding first

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with localized files in French, Italian, Spanish and German, on XCode 4 and UTF8 works fine for all those. I'm using Line Endings Default - Mac OS X / Unix. I recommend you first open the files on Text Wrangler, re save them as UTF8 and then try again with XCode. I don't mind taking a look at a piece of your file if you want to send it to me, my email is my user name here @gmail

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to open it on Safari Mobile, so I tried and successfully opened it on Safari for Mac. Now, I'm going to try @DimitarMarinov's suggestion, but I'm not certain that it will work. (I'm certain that it's a clunky solution, but, if it works, it works.)

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires UTF16 for the strings files, I know quite several cases where using UTF-8 will fail.

Also, do not use Windows line ending and check with the text editor like TextWrangler is the file is valid before putting it in Xcode.

BTW, Now is the first time when I head about **ANSI BOM** - there is no such thing, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody used `iconv` tool to do the trick? see `man iconv`